# Hide .synctex files

Tags: auxiliary-files, winedt, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

I use WinEdt 10.1 and Sumatrapdf. I find the inverse search extremely useful. However, the .synctex files are quite annoying to me because I work within a folder which contains up to a hundred latex files (and I arrange the files according to the time modified). In WinEdt, there is an option to put all the auxiliary files to a folder called "TeXAuX" which is very neat but somehow the .synctex file has to be in the same directory as the .tex file.

So my question is, is there a way (preferably by modifying the "compile" command within WinEdt's option) to change the attribute of the .synctex file to "hidden" immediately after compilation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't know, but I would find it quite useful  too that .synctex files might be located in a subdirectory of the main file directory.

Comment: That probably could be done on the TeX side, but how would SumatraPDF or other previewer know where to find the `.synctex` file?

Comment: @egreg, the OP doesn't want to move the `.synctex` file, but only to set its file attribute to "hidden".

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29948)

Answer (score 5):

There's no WinEdt macro that acts on the file attributes.

However we can tell WinEdt to use the `attrib` DOS command to achieve what you want.

These are the steps you have to follow:

1. Open the file `%B\Exec\ExeCompilerPost.edt` in WinEdt (`%B` is the directory where you've installed the program, something like `C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10`).
2. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface) and click on "Advanced Configuration":

   [image]
3. Now, in the Options Interface toolbar, click on the button "Create and Open Local Copy":

   [image]
4. A local copy of `ExeCompilerPost.edt` gets opened. In this file search for the following lines near the end of the file:

   ```
       IfFileExists("%O\%N.%!7",!"CopyFile('%O\%N.%!7','%P\%N.%!7',1);DeleteFile('%O\%N.%!7');");
       IfFileExists("%O\%N%$('PDF-SyncEx');",>
         !"CopyFile('%O\%N%$(|PDF-SyncEx|);','%P\%N%$(|PDF-SyncEx|);',1);DeleteFile('%O\%N%$(|PDF-SyncEx|);');");
     JMP(!"Post_Done");
   ```
5. Replace these lines with the following:

   ```
       IfFileExists("%O\%N.%!7",!"CopyFile('%O\%N.%!7','%P\%N.%!7',1);DeleteFile('%O\%N.%!7');");
       IfFileExists("%O\%N%$('PDF-SyncEx');",>
         !"CopyFile('%O\%N%$(|PDF-SyncEx|);','%P\%N%$(|PDF-SyncEx|);',1);DeleteFile('%O\%N%$(|PDF-SyncEx|);');");
       IfFileExists("%P\%N%$('PDF-SyncEx');",>
         !"WinExe('','cmd.exe /C attrib +h %N%$(|PDF-SyncEx|);','%P','',011100);");
     JMP(!"Post_Done");
   ```
6. Save the file and you're done.

---

Now, every time you compile a file, the associated synctex file is saved as a hidden file.

Comment: What is the idea behind step 1? Why open the original too?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is very likely that a local copy of `ExeCompilerPost.edt` doesn't exist in the OP's system. Unless you manually created it, only the [ChkTeX](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/ChkTeX.html) add-on creates a local copy and modifyes it.

Comment: Ah I see. I hadn't realized that there is no entry for the file in the option menu to "double click".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-output-directory="output"` (right side is dir name) parameter, like

```
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory="output" "something.tex"
```

so that your outupt will be placed in separate directory, but directory must exist, so that it can write in it. But I am not sure how it will work with inverse search.